# How can I send the POST request to the other server binding file into formdata

Tags: javascript, rest, web-services, post, form-data

I have a pdf file which is generated into my local server with my server side code. I want to send a request to the another server requesting `POST`. The post method take parameter as **FormData** where formdata types

> one is `string` and another is `file` type.

```
content-type
form-data
Body
 　PDF file (file type)
   string value
```

Is it possible to make the `POST` request without browsing the file location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some R&D I have overcome this problem with following some steps, as there is no way to get the file object from the physical location automatically in client side (basically in js) except browsing for security reason.

1. In my local server I have created a `REST` service. which response `base64 string` of the desired file.
2. Than I call the `REST api` from my `javaScript` and as a response I receive the `base64 string`. And than I convert it into `bytes array` and than `Blob` object and than `File` object.

   > base64 string==>bytes array==>Blob object==>File object

   ```
   var base64 = this.getpdfFromLocal() //get the base64 string
   var byteArray= this.base64ToByte(base64 );
   var file = this.getFileFromByteArray(byteArray);

   //return the byte array form the base64 string
   MyApi.prototype.base64ToByte= function(base64) {
       var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
       var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
       var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
       for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
           var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
           bytes[i] = ascii;
       }
       return bytes;
   };
   MyApi.prototype.getFileFromByteArray=function(byteArray) {
       var blob = new Blob([byteArray]);
       var file = new File([blob], "resource.pdf");
       return file;
    };
   ```
3. Lastly I make `from data` using file object and send request the another server `REST` web services.

   ```
   var formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append("some_value", "Some String");
   formdata.append("file", file);
   var url = "http://yoururl.com";
   var result =$.ajax({
       url             : url ,
       type            : 'POST',
       data            : formdata,
       contentType     : false,
       cache           : false,
       processData     : false,
       scriptCharset   : 'utf-8',
       async           : false
   }).responseText;
   ```